# How to make udev deamon "think" we have added a new rule?

Tags: c++, c, linux, udev

Does someone knows if its possible to access programmatically to the data structure where `udev` store the rules? And if its possible to modify them?

In short: I want to run a program and cause the same effect of adding a new rule without actually modify any `.rule` file. I want to keep it all in memory.

If this possible?  I was reading the [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) code looking for information about how `udevdaemon` reads `.rules` files and then "communicates" this rules to "somebody" in the kernel.

I think this "communication" is the key. But I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's it's possible to add `udev` rules by another means than configuration files. But if it is important for you, you can still mount a `tmpfs` on `/etc/udev/rules.d` and write your rules there, everything will happen in memory without hitting the disk. Or you can implement your own configuration mechanism in `src/udev/udev-rules.c`. The code would have to receive the configuration by whatever way you prefer and call `rules_add_string`.

Regarding the communication betweeen the kernel and `udev`, `udev` just reads kernel events from a socket and then applies its rules to create the appropriate devices in `/dev`. The kernel never receives the `udev` configuration and it doesn't care about it.